# Cyanogenmod - background of activity

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm programming an app on Android where there is a simple background image. It runs normally on every phone and emulators (native and Genymotion) I tested (5 devices), only 1 friend has this issue. Image of background is not displaying and instead of that there is a default black background. He is using KitKat 4.4.4 Cyanogenmod.

Here is the part of the layout of that Activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/orange_rubb" >
```

Comment: Presumably, if the referenced resource is assumed to be provided by the system and not shipped with the app, then it is one that doesn't exist in that AOSP-derived installation.

Comment: It is my own image and it is packed when generating .apk file